# What is my Gitlab domain for making API calls?

Tags: gitlab-api

I feel reaaally silly for asking this but how do I know what my Gitlab domain is when all my projects are on Gitlab.com? Lets say, I want to do an API call to get all my projects - which is done like this according to the docs:

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXX" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"`

I tried replacing `example` with my username and also tried specifying the target as `https://gitlab.com/username/api/v4/projects` but this doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Its actually just:

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects`

Your private token will be used to figure out who you are and what projects you can access.